# Why is there a gap in Bamboo tasks after Protractor is completed?

Tags: angularjs, selenium, continuous-integration, protractor, bamboo

I am seeing about a 2 minute gap in my bamboo build after my Protractor task is completed. See logs below:

```
[12/8/2015 5:10 PM] Agnew, Tyler: 
build   08-Dec-2015 16:45:24    Finished in 62.66 seconds
build   08-Dec-2015 16:45:24    [32m1 test, 1 assertion, 0 failures
build   08-Dec-2015 16:45:24    [0m
build   08-Dec-2015 16:45:24    SauceLabs results available at http://saucelabs.com/jobs/7d19c517399e4d118879f5e104ce0e71
build   08-Dec-2015 16:45:25    [launcher] 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
build   08-Dec-2015 16:45:25    [launcher] chrome #1 passed
build   08-Dec-2015 16:45:25    stopping gulp server...
build   08-Dec-2015 16:45:25    [16:45:25] Finished 'protractor:e2e' after 1.13 min
simple  08-Dec-2015 16:47:28    Finished task 'Run Protractor Tests' with result: Success
simple  08-Dec-2015 16:47:28    Starting task 'Parse Test Results' of type 'com.atlassian.bamboo.plugins.testresultparser:task.testresultparser.junit'
```

Does anyone know if there is something that I can add to my protractor task to kill as soon as "Finished protractor:e2e" log? I just want to move right on to the next task. I can't tell what is still hanging that is causing the delay.

Thanks,
Tyler

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out - gulp was not throwing Process.exit(0) on completion. Thats what Bamboo was looking for.